# How to get widget property directly in java script in adobe cq5 ?

Tags: aem

I have a widget in which my property name is "./title". i want to get this property value in javascript. for this i am getting its value in jsp.

JSP code

```
<div class="title">
 <%=properties.get("./title","PageTitle")%>
</div>
```

jquery

```
  $('.title').text();
```

By doing i'm able to get the value of title.But is there any other way through which i can get its value directly  in javascript . thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize a JS variable with this value.

```html
<script>
  var title = "<%=properties.get("./title","PageTitle")%>"
</script>
```